# Software design: use of data models and dependency between services

Tags: architecture

I want to hear some opinions on software design:

1. Data models

I'm currently developing software based on:

```
Controller
    Service
        Repository
```

and I'm not really sure whether it is a good practice to use different data models in each layer.

```
Controller -> Receives a DTO and converts it into a "service object"
    Service -> Receives a "service object" and converts it into a database entity
        Repository -> persists a database entity
```

It seems like a lot of duplicate code, as usually the information exchange in each layer doesn't differ much.

2. Dependency between services

Imagine you have two services
    Availability: checks for available dates
    Booking: makes reservations

Now, if when calling the Availability service, the date is available, then that date must be booked. How should that dependency be managed?

```
- Option 1: calling BookingService from inside AvailabilityService
    AvailabilityService {

        Calling BookingService

    }

- Option 2: calling BookingService after the response of AvailabilityService
    AvailabilityController {
        Calling AvailabilityService
        Calling BookingService (base on the response from AvailabilityService)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Question 1:
The model depends on who is "working" with the data. A persistence layer with an O/R mapper has a certain way of modeling objects (or to be precise: classes). On the other hand: A view in the browser (not in a DB) normally mixes data from different objets, therefore you create an customized DTO for that view containing exactly what that view needs to display. That also includes not to expose data which is not required by the view and avoid multiple requests (first this object, then that...). If further conversions are necessary has to be decided if another data structure is required by someone. I think this not a usual use case, normally you have to map data structures from a DB to the required data of the view.

Question 2: 
If your AvailabilityService only checks availability, it should not book. Otherwise the name would be false. In Option 2 the name of the controller is wrong, this is obviously not an AvailabilityController but something like an OrderController, be aware to choose good names (Clean Code).